# How to setup Lenovo IdeaPad Z500 Notebook Nvidia Optimus drivers?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia-optimus

I have installed the Ubuntu 12.04 on Lenovo IdeaPad Z500 Notebook.
Currently I don't know how to ascertain which card is being used and how to setup the appropriated drivers to use the Nvidia Optimus.

Answer (score 1):

i have same laptop with ubuntu 12.04. I simply installed bumblebee and primusrun with software center. after this install lenovo hack(needed for us laptop): https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/tree/hack-lenovo#lenovo-ideapad-y470y570-and-toshiba-satellite-p870
This work fine for me,hope this halp!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you and/or get you on the right track: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Luis

Answer (score 0):

What has so far worked for me with all computers that uses Nvidia drivers I've run the additional drivers program and tested the various ones that it finds and stick with the ones that gives me the best performance.

You'll find `Additional Drivers` as one of the tabs under `Software & Updates`.

Both can be found by a search string of the Ubuntu Launch button or under `System Settings` and choose `Software & Updates`.